# Swift - change table cell background in edit mode

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have table with user defined cells via XIB. My table supports edit mode to delete or rearange cells.

I have implemented

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Now, is there a way, how to change background of cells, while they are being in "edit mode"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need two delegate methods for this:

```
func tableView(UITableView, willBeginEditingRowAt: IndexPath)
```

> Tells the delegate that the table view is about to go into editing mode.

And

```
func tableView(UITableView, didEndEditingRowAt: IndexPath?)
```

> Tells the delegate that the table view has left editing mode.

You can implement each delegate method like this:

```
tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath).backgroundColor = someColor
```